# PHP array comparison to get total sum

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 set of array. The first array output the category and quantity, the second one comes with category and price.

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "Adult " => " 2"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    " Senior " => " 1"
  ]
]



array:3 [
  0 => array:6 [
    "id" => 1
    "variant_id" => 1
    "variant_dtl_name" => "Adult"
    "variant_dtl_price" => 25.0

  ]
  1 => array:6 [
    "id" => 2
    "variant_id" => 1
    "variant_dtl_name" => "Senior"
    "variant_dtl_price" => 15.0

  ]
  2 => array:6 [
    "id" => 3
    "variant_id" => 1
    "variant_dtl_name" => "Children"
    "variant_dtl_price" => 8.0

  ]
]
```

How can I cross match these two array to get total price? Eg: `Adult x 2` will output the price `50` and `Senior x 1` will output `15` and total would sum up to `65`. Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: just loop em all up, `foreach` should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it less costly, first make `$price_scale` containing category prices.

And then multiplying that in the first array to calculate the category price.

Assuming the first array's name as `$array1` ans second's `$array2`.

```
$price_scale = [];

foreach ($array2 as $arr)
{
    $price_scale[trim($arr['variant_dtl_name'])] = $arr['variant_dtl_price'];
}

$count = [];

foreach ($array1 as $arr)
{
    $key = key($arr); $name = trim($key);
    $count[$name] = $price_scale[$name] * $arr[$key];
}

print_r($count);
```

To get the total sum, just one more line

```
$sum = array_sum($count);
```

This foreach will iterate

(t1+t2) times

t1 = number of arrays in $array1
t2 = number of arrays in $array2

Comment: OK, how to sum back for each category?

Answer (score 4):

Try this out. Should work.
I think you understand what the `$secondArray` and `$thirdArray` are.
LEt me know the output.

```
<?php 

foreach($secondArray as $catKey => $cat){

    foreach($cat as $key=>$val){
        $categoryName = $key;
        $quantity = $val;
    }

    foreach($thirdArray as $catDetails){
        if($catDetails['variant_dtl_name'] == $categoryName){
            $secondArray[$catKey]['price'] = $catDetails['variant_dtl_price'] * $quantity;
            $price[] = $catDetails['variant_dtl_price'] * $quantity;
        }
    }
}

print_r($secondArray);

//Since You needed the total, you can do this.
    echo array_sum($price);
    ?>
```

Comment: it returns back the array 2.